# Filtering an Array Within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, arguments

I am doing a FreeCodeCamp challenge, "seek and destroy" where I create a function that removes elements from the array provided.

Given

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

The result should be

```
[1, 1]
```

While I have seen various solutions, I wanted so if I could make the solution I had been working on work because I it was intuitive to me and will hopefully lead me to a better understanding of filtering. I think the reason my solution is not working is because I am not properly using the method.

```
filter();
```

Anyway, here is my attempt:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
//makes the arguments an array

function destroy(value) {


for (var i=1; i < args.length; i++) 
return value !==args[i];
// creates a loop that filters all arguments after the first one and removes from the initial argument, regardless of how many there are. 

}

var filtered = arr.filter(destroy);
return arr[0];
}


destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I noticed that

```
var filtered = arr.filter(destroy);
```

Is likely the problem because the initial three arguments are being filtered, but not first argument. However, if I try doing

var filtered = arr[0].filter(destroy);
Which I thought would target that first argument, an error is thrown.
Is it possible to solve the problem this way? I wanted to do it this way because I like the way the following function is setup:

```
function badValues(val){  
 return val !== 2;   
}

function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(badValues);  
}

bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]);
```

And wanted to substitute 2 for the arguments that need to be removed.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `function destroyer() {
  let args = Array.from(arguments);
  let array = args[0];
  args.shift();
  return array.filter(e => !args.includes(e))
}`

Comment: Your `destroyer()` function only takes one argument, yet you are passing it three.

Comment: There are several problems to your implementation. For example, your `destroy` function returns at 1st iteration. Learn about javascript built-in functions like `find`, `filter`, ... will make your code cleaner, smarter, more readable.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/5c36gnjx/) is a working example, if you want to discover the solution by yourself, don't read it, if you really want to solve this and learn, you need to [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) how `filter` works. You are close.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  var filtered = arr.filter(destroy);  

  // you must return the filtered array
  return filtered;

  function destroy(value) {    
    for (var i=1; i < args.length; i++){

      // you must return false if you find it so filter removes the value
      if (value === args[i]) return false;
    }

    // if you loop through all and don't find it, return true so filter keeps the value
    return true;
  }
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I did try reading how filter works, but it was difficult for me to understand. I am particularly confused because in a similar problem, 
      function badValues(val){  
     return val !== false && val !== null && val !== 0 && val !== "" && val 
 !== undefined && !Number.isNaN(val);   
}

    function bouncer(arr) {
      return arr.filter(badValues);  
   }

   bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]);           The function works without using true and false to remove values.

Comment: Actually booleans are involved in that solution. When you use "!==" you are using a comparison operator, all sentences with that operator returns a boolean. [Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp).